# How to track a changes inside the table and refresh materialized view?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have pretty simple table in **PostgreSQL** database which looks like this:

```
| ID | REPORT_TYPE | STATUS | USER_EMAIL     |
|--------------------------------------------|
| 1  | sms         | 0      | bob@gmail.com  |
| 2  | call        | 1      | mark@gmail.com |
| 3  | internet    | 2      | kate@gmail.com |
```

Lets call this table `REPORTS`. I created **Materialized View** (`REPORTS_MV`) which has all records with status 0 from the table.

*Question*:
If someone change the values inside the table, I want to change that values inside the materialized view too. How to track a changes inside the table and refresh materialized view?

Comment: Try creating trigger on the table to refresh the materialized view whenever an insert occurs

Comment: Thank you for information. Can you show me some example?